# Failed to start the program, error spawn ${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin ENOENT

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

Trying to set up vscode for java and faced problem when trying to run even simpliest stuff. Failed to start the program, error spawn ${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin ENOENT, and then suggest to open launch.json.
Seen similar cases, tried to put direct way to bin in jdkPath, still the same,
[link to pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmM4t.png)

Here is original file:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Console App",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried to run same files in IntelliJ IDEA - work fine, but I want to stick with vs for now

Comment: where is the `jdkPath` configuration option documented? I can't find it with a quick google.

Comment: Where did you configure `{env:JAVA_HOME}`, can you show the details?